# How get sum of weighted 'tensor-multipllication' vectors without loop?

Tags: matlab, matrix, matrix-multiplication, vector-multiplication

I have groups of scalars and two groups of vectors respertively:

```
w1, w2... wn
b1, b2... bn
c1, c2... cn
```

`w1, w2... wn` are scalars and stored in `w`,
`b1, b2... bn` stored in `B` and
`c1, c2... cn` stored in `C`. How efficiently get

```
w1*(b1*c1') + w2*(b2*c2') + ... + wn*(bn*cn')
```

Where `bi` and `ci` are vectors but `bi*ci'` is matrix, not a scalar?
Sizes: `1 x N` for `w`, `P x N` for `B` and `Q x N` for `C`. `wi = w(i)`, `bi = B(:, i)` and `Ci = C(:, i)`

Comment: What shape do `w`, `B` and `C` have?. Do we assume they expand the `n` elements in the  third dimension?

Comment: Updated my post, add sizes.

Answer (score 1):

Simply:

```
result = B*diag(W)*C';
```

If `N` is much bigger than `P` and `Q`, you might prefer to compute the weight matrix `diag(W)` in its sparse form with `spdiags(W', 0, N, N)` instead.

Comment: Looks like the true, thank you. I think about your formula and perhaps, something like `bsxfun(@times, w, B) * C'` can be little faster.

Comment: Yes looks good, it's gonna depend on your particular dimensions `P`, `Q` and `N`.